# Mechanize with SSL thru proxy error

Tags: ruby, ssl, proxy, rubygems, mechanize

My code:

```
require 'machanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent = 'Mac Safari'

page = agent.get 'https://github.com
```

Everything is ok. But here what i've got if try to use proxy

```
require 'machanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent = 'Mac Safari'
agent.set_proxy 'X.X.X.X', <port>

page = agent.get 'https://github.com
```

i've got

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

I've also tried to turn off validation of cert, trying different certs and other. Any way, this error i've only got when trying to use proxy. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's a mitm proxy then this should be happening and you might want to disable ssl verify

Comment: @pguardiario i already solve problem thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem in 'openssl' program. I've installed postgresql.app on my system and it change PATH env to it self. So, same programs comes from poesgresql.app and openssl too. Problem was solved with correcting path, to make system's openssl preferred by default.